# PERGO Locking Hardwood Flooring in wet areas?

Tags: installation

Can I install PERGO Locking Hardwood Flooring in wet areas?

Comment: What do you mean by *wet areas*? Bathroom? Shower stalls? Kitchen? Basements prone to flooding?

Answer (score 1):

No. Wood flooring needs it to be dry. This is one reason that wood flooring is not usually recommended for mounting on concrete floors where the concrete rests on soil.